# DOM Manipulation of Telerik Text Editor

Tags: javascript, dom, telerik, telerik-editor

I am trying to manipulate a Telerik Text Editor element with JavaScript. I am using the following code:

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadEditor1_contentIframe").childNodes
```

Example of Telerik Text Editor @ http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

However, I get the following error: "Your browser does not support inline frames or is currently configured not to display them" with all major browsers.

Does any DOM ninja out there know how to solve this? I want to set the text value to a string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
var newContent = "New content here...",
iframe = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadEditor1_contentIframe");
```

The following line changes the whole thing:

```
iframe.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + newContent; //to change the whole iframe
```

Or, you can change the iframe body only:

```
iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].innerHTML = newContent; //to change body only
```

Comment: By changing the body only, you wont lose the editor capability of the  'text editor'.

Comment: Thanks, the last line of code really helped me out. You're a DOM Ninja for sure!